# Tabela está em mutação, trigger não a pode ler ou modificar

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Tenho uma tabela convocatoria(Hora, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, MinutosJogados) Onde minutos jogados são normalmente 90. No entando,Tenho uma tabela Acao(Hora, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, Minuto, TipoAcaoID) E o problema é, se um jogador tem um cartão vermelho (TipoAcaoID = 8), por example) no minuto 32, a tabela convocatoria devia mudar os minutos jogados para 32.

Isto é o meu trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    ContagemAmarelos INT;
    ContagemVermelhos INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemAmarelos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemVermelhos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    IF ContagemAmarelos = 2 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
            
    ELSIF ContagemVermelhos = 1 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes 
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

O trigger compila, mas quando tento inserir valores em ações tenho o erro que pus no titulo.

Comment: Este é problema relativamente comum , uma pesquisa e vai achar possíveis soluções , em inglês "mutating table".

Answer (score -2):

Você está tentando atualizar a tabela CONVOCATORY no gatilho check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon disparado pela tabela ACOES. No entanto, esta operação causa um erro de modificação da tabela.

Um gatilho é acionado em resposta a uma operação em uma tabela e qualquer tentativa de acessar ou modificar a mesma tabela em um gatilho causa um conflito.

Uma solução comum para esse problema é usar um trigger `BEFORE` em vez de um trigger `AFTER`.

Aqui está um exemplo de código com uma solução:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    ContagemAmarelos INT;
    ContagemVermelhos INT;
    MinutosJogados INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemAmarelos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemVermelhos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    IF ContagemAmarelos = 2 THEN
        SELECT Minuto INTO MinutosJogados
        FROM Acoes
        WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
            
    ELSIF ContagemVermelhos = 1 THEN
        SELECT Minuto INTO MinutosJogados
        FROM Acoes 
        WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    END IF;
    
    :NEW.MinutosJogados := MinutosJogados;
END;
/
```

Esta solução ajudou?